VectorColorFunction to use another function for the color
I would like to make a vector plot where the vector is a multivariable function of $x$ and $y$ and the color of the vector is another function (like the $z$ component of the vector effectively).
Here is what I have so far.
R = 1/4 
\[Theta][x_, y_] := \[Pi] - 4  ArcTan[Exp[-((x^2 + y^2)/R^2)]];
\[Phi][x_, y_] := ArcTan[x, y] - \[Pi]/2;

VectorPlot[{Cos[\[Phi][x, y]]  Sin[\[Theta][x, y]], 
Sin[\[Phi][x, y]]  Sin[\[Theta][x, y]]}, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, 
VectorScale -> {0.05, Automatic, None}, 
VectorColorFunction -> 
Function[{x, y}, ColorData["LakeColors"][Cos[\[Theta][x, y]]]], 
VectorColorFunctionScaling -> False]

which generates the following figure, but I have been unable to get it to plot the full range (-1,1) of the $\cos(\theta(x,y))$ function I have given it. I have tried about every normalization / rescaling, or explicit setting of bounds I could find on SE, to no avail. 

The vector plot is being clipped, which is made clear by changing the ClippingStyle
R = 1/4;
\[Theta][x_, y_] := \[Pi] - 4   ArcTan[Exp[-((x^2 + y^2)/R^2)]];
\[Phi][x_, y_] := ArcTan[x, y] - \[Pi]/2;

VectorPlot[{Cos[\[Phi][x, y]]   Sin[\[Theta][x, y]], 
    Sin[\[Phi][x, y]]   Sin[\[Theta][x, y]]}, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, 
   VectorColorFunction -> Function[{x, y}, ColorData["Rainbow"][Cos[\[Theta][x, y]]]], 
   VectorColorFunctionScaling -> False, 
   ClippingStyle -> #] & /@ {Automatic, None}


Using "Rainbow" because it's easier to see
ColorData["Rainbow", "Image"]


Prevent clipping with VectorRange -> All
VectorPlot[{Cos[\[Phi][x, y]]   Sin[\[Theta][x, y]], 
  Sin[\[Phi][x, y]]   Sin[\[Theta][x, y]]}, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, 
 VectorColorFunction -> Function[{x, y}, ColorData["Rainbow"][Cos[\[Theta][x, y]]]], 
 VectorColorFunctionScaling -> False, VectorRange -> All]


To see more resolution in the color function, increase the VectorPoints
VectorPlot[{Cos[\[Phi][x, y]]   Sin[\[Theta][x, y]], 
  Sin[\[Phi][x, y]]   Sin[\[Theta][x, y]]}, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, 
 VectorColorFunction -> Function[{x, y}, ColorData["Rainbow"][Cos[\[Theta][x, y]]]], 
 VectorColorFunctionScaling -> False, VectorRange -> All, 
 VectorPoints -> Fine]


This matches the expected color of Cos[\[Theta][x, y]]
Plot3D[Cos[\[Theta][x, y]], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, PlotRange -> All, 
 ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", PlotPoints -> 50]


